# Spark SASL not working on the emr with yarn

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

So first, I want to say the only thing I have seen address this issue is here: [Spark 1.6.1 SASL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269113/spark-1-6-1-sasl). However, when adding the configuration for the spark and yarn authentication, it is still not working. Below is my configuration for spark using spark-submit on a yarn cluster on amazon's emr:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("secure-test");
    sparkConf.set("spark.authenticate.enableSaslEncryption", "true");
    sparkConf.set("spark.network.sasl.serverAlwaysEncrypt", "true");
    sparkConf.set("spark.authenticate", "true");
    sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    sparkConf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "org.nd4j.Nd4jRegistrator");
    try {
        sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
                Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"),
                Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.enableServerSideEncryption", "true");
    sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.authenticate", "true");
```

Note, I added the spark.authenticate to the sparkContext's hadoop configuration in code instead of the core-site.xml (which I am assuming I can do that since other things work as well).

Looking here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/common/network-yarn/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/network/yarn/YarnShuffleService.java it seems like both spark.authenticate's are necessary. When I run this application, I get the following stack trace.

> 17/01/03 22:10:23 INFO storage.BlockManager: Registering executor with local external shuffle service.
>   17/01/03 22:10:23 ERROR client.TransportClientFactory: Exception while bootstrapping client after 178 ms
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message type: -22
>       at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.BlockTransferMessage$Decoder.fromByteBuffer(BlockTransferMessage.java:67)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.receive(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:71)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:149)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:102)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:104)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>       at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>       at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:86)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
>       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
>       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
>       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

In Spark's docs, it says

```
For Spark on YARN deployments, configuring spark.authenticate to true will automatically handle generating and distributing the shared secret. Each application will use a unique shared secret.
```

which seems wrong based on the comments in the yarn file above, but with trouble shooting, I am still lost on where I should go to get sasl to work? Am I missing something obvious that is documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. The previous StackOverflow thread was technically correct. I needed to add the spark.authenticate to the yarn configuration. Maybe it is possible to do this, but I can't figure out how to add this configuration in the code, which makes sense at a high level why this is the case. I will post my configuration below in case anyone else runs into this issue in the future.

First, I used an aws emr configurations file (An example of this is when using aws cli `aws emr create-cluster --configurations file://youpathhere.json`)

Then, I added the following json to the file:

```
[{
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
        "spark.authenticate": "true",
        "spark.authenticate.enableSaslEncryption": "true",
        "spark.network.sasl.serverAlwaysEncrypt": "true"
    }
},
{
    "Classification": "core-site",
    "Properties": {
        "spark.authenticate": "true"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message on Spark on Dataproc (Google Cloud Platform) after I added  configuration options for Spark network encryption.

I initially created the Dataproc cluster with the following command.

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create test-encryption --no-address \
--service-account=<SERVICE-ACCOUNT> \
--zone=europe-west3-c --region=europe-west3 \
--subnet=<SUBNET> \
--properties 'spark:spark.authenticate=true,spark:spark.network.crypto.enabled=true'
```

The solution was to add in addition the configuration `'yarn:spark.authenticate=true'`. A working Dataproc cluster with RPC encryption of Spark can therefore be created as follows.

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create test-encryption --no-address \
--service-account=<SERVICE-ACCOUNT> \
--zone=europe-west3-c --region=europe-west3 \
--subnet=<SUBNET> \
--properties 'spark:spark.authenticate=true,spark:spark.network.crypto.enabled=true,yarn:spark.authenticate=true'
```

I verified the encryption with ngrep. I installed ngrep as follows on the master node.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ngrep
```

I then run ngrep on an arbitrary port 20001.

```
sudo ngrep port 20001
```

If you then run a Spark job with the following configuration properties you can see the encrypted communication between driver and worker nodes.

```
spark.driver.port=20001
spark.blockManager.port=20002
```

Note, I would always advice also to enable Kerberos on Dataproc to secure authentication for Hadoop, Yarn etc. This can be achieved with the flag `--enable-kerberos` in the cluster creation command.